# Whats the difference between a range of a set(a,b) and union of all elements of sets in (a,b)?

Tags: c++

Beginner here. Wrote a program to check if entered alphabet is lowercase or upppercase. (Practising if/else questions)
I thought of two methods:

1. Range method-getting the desired result
2. Union method-not getting the desired result

Here is the code,

```
if (enteredAlphabet>='a' && enteredAlphabet <='z')
{
    cout<<enteredAlphabet<<" is lowercase.";
}
```

and

```
if (enteredAlphabet==('a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'f'||'g'||'h'||'i'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'o'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'u'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z'))
{
    cout<<enteredAlphabet<<" is lowercase.";
}
```

Comment: The second one is `if (enteredAlphabet==1)`.

Comment: First method works with ASCII, but not with EBCDIC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `'a'||'b'||...` is actually a short-hand for `('a' != 0) || ('b' != 0) || ...`.

The result of the expression will always be the boolean value `true`.

Since `true` can be converted to the integer value `1` your comparison is really the same as `enteredAlphabet == 1`. This comparison will likely *never* be true.

What you *actually* should use is [`std::islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower):

```
if (std::islower(enteredAlphabet)) { /* Is lower case letter */ }
```